# Chrome resizes svg images

Tags: image, google-chrome, angularjs, svg

I have an img menu with svg images that changes the svg image with a identical image with a different color when you push in menu. When I test it with Chrome it works fine until you visit one link the second time, that chrome resize it to a smaller image. 
I've made a lot of tests... I've tested :visited css, user agent css, and many another properties and it seems to be all ok. When you changes some css property in developer tools it changes automagically to correct size.
My last test was to change the width from 135px to 134px (don't ask why) and it works in 1680x1050 screen but not in 1920x1200 screen (???????). Is it an aspect ratio problem?
I'm getting crazy!!
I'm using angularjs to make the black image to red image change, but I think this is not the problem (it does a src replacement)

You can see it in the webpage http://silviaperezcruz.com.

I'll apreciate any kind of help.

PD: Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see an obvious reason why it is doing it,. But if I had to guess, I would cast a suspicious eye on respond.js first.  Does it still do it if you remove that?